# How to correct my code to remove CORS Problem to fetch?

Tags: java, angularjs, reactjs, spring-boot, fetch

Good afternoon!I get error "Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:8080/registration' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled."
I am trying to put information from web app angular, react into java app(spring boot). I looked many different links and did not find where the error in code is.
here is my Registration.js, I suppose there is a mistake, but cannot find where.

```
import fetch from "node-fetch";

    class Registration extends Component{
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
       this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
        this.state = {
                username: '',
                password: '',
                confirmPassword: '',
                user_fullname: '',
                user_email: '',
                company_name: '',
                position_name: '',
        };      
    }
    handleChange = (event, title) => this.setState({[title]: event.target.value});

    handleSubmit = async event => {
 event.preventDefault();
        this.setState({isloading: true});
        console.log(this.state);
        const headers: HttpHeaders = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/json;charset=UTF-8')
            .append('Content-type', 'application/json;')
            .append('Accept','application/json')
            .append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
        return fetch('http://localhost:8080/registration',
            { mode:"no-cors" , headers: headers, method:"POST" ,body:this.state}
            ).then(response => {
            console.log(response);
        })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error)
            })
    };
    render() {
        return (
            <form method="POST" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} action="/registration">
                <FormGroup controlId="username" bssize="large">
                    <FormControl name="username" value={this.state.username} type="text" onChange={ this.handleUsernameChange} />
                </FormGroup>

                <FormGroup controlId="password" bssize="large">
                    <FormControl name="password"  value={this.state.password} onChange={this.handlePasswordChange} type="text" />
                </FormGroup>

                <FormGroup controlId="confirmPassword" bssize="large">
                    <FormControl name="confirmPassword" value={this.state.confirmPassword}  onChange={this.handleConfirmPasswordChange} type="text"/>
                </FormGroup>

                <FormGroup controlId="user_fullname" bssize="large">
                    <FormControl name="user_fullname" value={this.state.user_fullname}  type="text" onChange={this.handleUser_FullnameChange} />
                </FormGroup>

                <FormGroup controlId="user_email" bssize="large">
                    <FormControl name="user_email" value={this.state.user_email} type="text" onChange={this.handleUser_emailChange} />
                </FormGroup>

                <FormGroup controlId="company_name" bssize="large">
                    <FormControl name="company_name"  value={this.state.company_name} type="text" onChange={this.handleCompany_nameChange} />
                </FormGroup>

                <FormGroup controlId="position_name" bssize="large">
                    <FormControl name="position_name" value={this.state.position_name} type="text" onChange={this.handlePosition_nameChange} />
                </FormGroup>

                <Button bssize="large" type="submit"> Registration </Button>
            </form>
        );
    }}export default  Registration;
```

My UserController.java

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/registration", method = {RequestMethod.POST}, produces={"application/json"})
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<User> registration(@RequestBody  User user, HttpStatus httpStatus) {
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.valueOf(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE));
         userService.saveUser(user);
         return new ResponseEntity<User>(user,  HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }
     @GetMapping("/registration")
    public String registration(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("userForm", new User());

        return "registration";
    }
```

User.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "username")
    private String username;

    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;
    @Transient
    @Column(name = "confirmPassword")
    private String confirmPassword;

    @Column(name = "user_fullname")
    private String user_fullname;

    @Column(name = "user_email")
    private String user_email;

    @Column(name = "company_name")
    private String company_name;

    @Column(name = "position_name")
    private String position_name;
    @Column(name = "date")
    private Date date = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());


    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "user_roles", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id"))
    private Set<Roles> roles;
    public User(){

}
    public User(Integer id,String username, String password, String confirmPassword, String user_fullname, String user_email,String company_name, String position_name ){
this.id = id;
this.username=username;
this.password = password;
this.confirmPassword = confirmPassword;
this.user_fullname = user_fullname;
this.user_email = user_email;
this.company_name = company_name;
this.position_name = position_name;
    }


    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getConfirmPassword() {
        return confirmPassword;
    }

    public void setConfirmPassword(String confirmPassword) {
        this.confirmPassword = confirmPassword;
    }

    public String getUser_fullname() {
        return user_fullname;
    }

    public void setUser_fullname(String user_fullname) {
        this.user_fullname = user_fullname;
    }

    public String getUser_email() {
        return user_email;
    }

    public void setUser_email(String user_email) {
        this.user_email = user_email;
    }

    public String getCompany_name() {
        return company_name;
    }

    public void setCompany_name(String company_name) {
        this.company_name = company_name;
    }

    public String getPos_name() {
        return position_name;
    }

    public void setPos_name(String position_name) {
        this.position_name = position_name;
    }


    public Set<Roles> getRoles() {
        return roles;
    }
    public void setRoles(Set<Roles> roles) {
        this.roles = roles;
    }

    public Date getDate() {
        return date;
    }


}
```

Users db

```
CREATE TABLE users (
  id       INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  username VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL ,
  password VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL ,
  user_fullname VARCHAR(255),
  user_email    VARCHAR(255) ,
  company_name VARCHAR(255),
  position_name VARCHAR(255),
  date DATETIME
)
  ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Comment: What is the purpose of `var payload = { ... }`? You don't use `payload` for anything, except as return value from `handleSubmit`, which makes no sense at all, since an `onSubmit` handler should return a boolean value.

Comment: @Andreas thank you for recommendations. Yes, i supposed to use it like the array of parameters, but i rewrite the code without the payload. But I still have null in backend, even i changed ModelAttribute on RequestBody, and set "Content-Type" in headers. But after I got that "fetch " on Window : Invalid name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you have a problem with Spring Boot security. Assuming you have Spring Boot security enabled, based on the error message you've received "Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check", you need to allow pre-flight request in the back-end. You can try to create a new class and extend WebSecurityConfigurerAdaptor like so:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(Http.OPTIONS, "/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
            .httpBasic();
    }
}
```

Http.OPTIONS are pre-flight requests send to the server to make sure you have the right authentication to retrieve the resource. Here, you are permitting all pre-flight requests to let the actual request retrieve the resource.

Answer (score 1):

Like @Andreas has Mentioned use `@RequestBody` instead of `@ModelAttribute` ( I believe @ModelAttribute annotation binds a method parameter) and also in client side you are posting that as JSON.
So try using below

```java
@PostMapping(value = "/registration")
public String registration(@RequestBody User userForm, BindingResult bindingResult) {
 //Code Logic
}
```

Comment: thank you, I changed the line, but still get the error

Comment: Hey @NataliHachok, log the `body: JSON.stringify(this.state)`, and also you are setting the state to the payload but not posting that, can you check  `var payload`

Comment: thank you for recommendation,  I checked it and rewrote the code, but also if I use RequestBody as here was recommeded, then I have an error 415 (unsupported MediaType), even i set Content_Type . I get other error that "Failed to execute 'fetch' on Window :Invalid name". I supposeI have a problem in UserController because I debbuged "userForm" is null even a browser console sends  parameters

Comment: @NataliHachok If you rewrote the code, edit the question and show us the new code. The unsupported MediaType is likely because of the `Accept` header, so remove that. In addition, use the browsers developer tools to see what is actually being transmitted. In FireFox, and I believe Chrome too, press F12 and select the "Network" tab, then perform the operation again.

Comment: @Andreas thank you. I tried to use your recommendations, but i still have problems with it. I posted new question. Thank you for your help

Comment: Hey @NataliHachok.. if you still get that the problem try posting it using `Postman` or `RestClient`.May be hard code the `payload object` and you don't need to `Stringify` just `body: this.state` and try

Comment: @Avi HI! i edited the question. I rewrote the question. But I still have an error. thank you

Answer (score 0):

I believe `@ModelAttribute` only maps *request parameters*, i.e. values from query string or from form POST content with content type `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` or `multipart/form-data`.

Since you're sending the data as JSON, you need to change annotation to `@RequestBody`.